# Web application security by mac

Tags: java, security

How can I restrict the access to a java web application per machine (could be by the mac of the device)? I really don't know how to do that

Is a cryptotoken to store a SSL certificate the best approach?

I am using Wildfly 8
JSF 2.2
Primefaces 5.2

Comment: Depends on the environment. Within a corporate environment you may use the IP of the device. But this can be faked. You should rely on user credentials and not on device information.

Comment: The IP's are generated by DHCP through the ISP

Comment: MAC is not accessible over HTTP. MAC can also be changed.

What are you actually, more generally, trying to accomplish (without stating a solution)

Comment: I need to restrict access of my web application to users that I want. Only users that have an user and a password can access to my web application through a specific machine (windows, linux)

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses aren't available over the internet.

IPs seem to be outside of your control (the ISP controls them).

The simplest solution is to implement a Basic Auth challenge on the server. If that doesn't match your security needs, then yes, client side certificates are the safest way to go.

Comment: Basic auth challenge on the server means only user and password authentication?